# AutoParallaxBackground vertically in GLES2, AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

How do I move an AutoParallaxBackground vertically in andengine? This is such a simple problem, but I can't find a solution to it!

I use GLES2, and I use the code that code in the example that comes with AndEngine http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/AutoParallaxBackgroundExample.java.

The thing is that you can't change or add vertical speed anywhere since there is no class created for the AutoParallaxBackground - it is only the parameters in the main class that you can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no easy way to do that. You will have to modify it to suit your needs, which should be easy enough.

Edit: For some reason, this question popped up in my feed again, so I looked into the matter a bit more. I believe the key to make this work is to change the method `onDraw` of `ParallaxEntity`. There is a call to OpenGL's `glTranslatef` method which has only one of the three parameters (x, y, z) filled in, so the obvious solution would be to provide the second parameter as well.

Comment: Solved, it now ... Just did own rules for how to move it.

Comment: Well, it is not the prettiest thing I've done ... I just made a picture, twice the size of the screen. Then I made it move constantly with the speed I wanted, and when it got out of the screen I moved it back, with an if statement. I guess there are better ways to do it, but it worked good enough.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the game in landscape mode and rotate your image in such a way that it will feel like background is scrolling vertically.
otherwise use a image and set a physicalHandler to set it velocity in vertical direction and reset it to it initial position.